# What's the difference between inform and notify?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

What's the difference between those when somebody said:

1. I'll inform you.
2. I'll notify you.

Comment: Did you mean to say *I'll notify you*? "I'll notice you." sounds weird.

Comment: You should add more information or context. And as @Kris said, "notice" does seem to be oddly used.

Comment: I'm wondering if you might have asked this on [ell.se], had you noticed that site existed. I hope you don't mind me informing you about ELL.

Comment: @Kris yes, you are right. That's the word I'd like to use, modify it right away.

Comment: Thanks @J.R. to point out the [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). Should I post this kind of question there?

Comment: @haudoing - Yes, but leave this particular question here. (Cross-posting questions is considered a no-no on the Stack Exchange.) However, this type of question is probably better suited for ELL; so feel free to ask further questions over there.

Comment: Though I feel said of the down vote, I feel happy to get many help from people. Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 2):

"Inform" means "tell." It means you give someone new information.

For example: "I'll inform you of the score of the football game." Is the same as "I'll tell you score of the football game."

"Notice" is similar to "see." It means you now know something or see something you didn't know or see before.

"I'll notice you in the restaurant." This is the same as "I'll see you in the restaurant."

Also, "inform" can take an indirect object, with "of", but "notice" cannot have an indirect object. You can "inform me of the news," but you cannot "notice me the news."

Comment: I am surprised if there really is such a meaning/ usage to *notice* as *"I'll notice you in the restaurant." This is the same as "I'll see you in the restaurant."* -- What is the source?

Comment: Yes: you might say "I noticed him in the restaurant," but it's unlikely to be used in the future tense. By your own definition, you shouldn't know he will be there.

Comment: Consider changing the sentence to: "I noticed you ..." is the same as "I saw ..."

Comment: @AndrewLeach It's possible, as part of a larger sentence: "If you are wearing that garish hat, I'm sure I will notice you in the restaurant."

Answer (score 1):

*Notice* does appear in OED with the meaning of *notify* or *inform*, but it notes "now rare". It does cite a recent quotation:

> 1997   P. Cornwell *Unnatural Exposure* viii. 189   ‘I assume you've been inside the house.’.. ‘I haven't. Was a neighbour that did. And when I was noticed about it, I called for Norfolk.’

It's unusual enough to give one pause. However that use **could** be used in the future tense ("I'll notice you tomorrow"), because one might say "I'll inform you tomorrow."

The normal use of *notice* is what they give as sense 3 (some of which is marked obsolete):

> **a.** *trans.* To take notice of; to observe, to become aware of.
>   **b.** *intr.* To take notice; to observe or become aware of what is happening.
>   **d.** *colloq.* **not so as you'd notice** (and variants): not to a noticeable degree.
>   **e.** *intr.* To be seen, to be noticeable, to show.

In these meanings, particularly the transitive use **3a**, it would be grammatically correct but semantically dubious to use *notice* in the future tense. One would not normally say "I'll become aware of you in the restaurant tomorrow".

Comment: -1 This example is nothing about future tense, esp., in the sense of *to see* or *to inform*. Nothing else you have stated helps answer the question. No offense.

Comment: @Kris Not sure what your comment has to do with the answer. If the example in the question is nothing to do with the future tense, then the meaning I have illustrated here (notify/inform) can still legitimately be used. If it **is** to do with the future tense, then the meaning I have illustrated here can again be legitimately used. That doesn't stop it being unusual. And if *notice* does **not** mean *notify/inform* but rather sense **3a** here, then the future tense is unrealistic [as we agreed in your earlier comment.]

Comment: Let's wait till the OP clarifies what exactly he meant to say.

Comment: OK. Perhaps you'd like to withdraw your downvote then.

Comment: Sure, edit your answer to include the argument presented in the comment, and if that works, the down vote will be gone.